# How to invoke AWS lambda from another lambda within SAM local?

Tags: python, aws-lambda, boto3

I am using AWS SAM with Python. My goal is to have two Lambdas:

- Function A: A normal synchronous Lambda which will invoke Function B, then return quickly
- Function B: A long-running asynchronous Event Lambda

There are a couple other SO questions which deal with this scenario, but as far as I can tell none have touched on how to do it when deploying SAM locally.

Here is my SAM template file:

```
# template.yaml

Resources:
  FunctionA:
    # PUT /functions/a, should invoke FunctionB asynchronously
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: api/
      Handler: functions.a
      Runtime: python3.7
      Events:
        FunctionA:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /functions/a
            Method: put

  FunctionB:
    # Long-running asynchronous function
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: 'FunctionB'
      CodeUri: api/
      Handler: functions.b
      Runtime: python3.7
      EventInvokeConfig:
        MaximumRetryAttempts: 2
        DestinationConfig:
          OnSuccess:
            Type: SQS
          OnFailure:
            Type: SQS
```

And my Python lambda handler logic:

```py
# functions.py

def a(event, context):
  boto3.client('lambda').invoke(
    FunctionName='FunctionB',
    InvocationType='Event',
    Payload='some_data'.encode('UTF-8')
  )
  return { "statusCode": 200, "body": {} }

def b(data):
  print("SUCCESS!")
```

I deploy it locally:

```
# deploy.sh
sam build
sam local start-api
```

All is well until this point. When I call `PUT /functions/a`, I get the following error indicating that Function B could not be invoked from Function A:

```
[ERROR] ResourceNotFoundException: An error occurred (ResourceNotFoundException) when calling the Invoke operation: Function not found: arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:[iam-user-id]:function:FunctionB
```

Has anyone found a fix for this? Here's what I've tried:

1. Verified that Function B can be invoked successfully via the command line:

```
sam local invoke FunctionB # works great
```

2. Attempted to change the `InvocationType=Event` to `InvocationType=RequestResponse` and received the same error
3. Instantiated the lambda client to reference the local URL

```py
boto3.client('lambda', endpoint_url='http://localhost:3000')
# [ERROR] EndpointConnectionError: Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "http://localhost:3000/2015-03-31/functions/ScheduleShowsAsyncFunction/invocations"
```

Comment: I feel your pain, I'm in the same place.  I suspect it's because the generated Lambdas are suffixed with an ID to keep them unique between multiple deployments (e.g. FunctionB-123ABC4DE5F6A), so a Lamba named "FunctionB" doesn't exist.

Comment: Short Answer: Use the Environment Property of the function for passing it arbitrary text from the template. Get the attribute Arn from the other Function with the intrinsic function GetAtt and use it as the "arbitrary text" you'll pass in the environment. Then simple get the value from the system environment in your code (os.environ.get("OTHER_FUNCTION_ARN")).

Answer (score 5):

You can use [sam local start-lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-cli-command-reference-sam-local-start-lambda.html) to run FunctionA, it will emulates on port 3001, and call it from FunctionB with lambda client:

`boto3.client('lambda', endpoint_url='http://docker.for.mac.localhost:3001')`

You have to use `InvocationType=RequestResponse` because Event is not yet supported https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sam-cli/pull/749

If FunctionB is long-running and because you can only use RequestResponse you can change lambda client config to increase timeout:

```
config_lambda = Config(retries={'total_max_attempts': 1}, read_timeout=1200)

lambda_client = boto3.client('lambda',
                             config=config_lambda,
                             endpoint_url='http://docker.for.mac.localhost:3001')
```