# Invocation Issue: SAM Application - Error with async invocation of lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sam

I have a SAM app in nodejs18x runtime consisting of two Lambda functions, **`HelloWorldFunction`** and **`HelloWorldFunctionB`**. I'm trying to invoke **`HelloWorldFunctionB`**  asynchronously from **`HelloWorldFunction`** using the AWS SDK. However, I'm encountering an issue where the invocation is not working as expected.

In production, I get the error - **`ResourceNotFoundException: Function not found: arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:xxxxxxxxxxx:function:HelloWorldFunctionB`**.

Locally, I get the error **`ResourceNotFoundException: Function not found at constructor.callListeners`**

Here is the code of both functions and template.yaml

**HelloWorldFunction (the invoker)**

```js
export const lambdaHandler = async (event: APIGatewayProxyEvent): Promise<APIGatewayProxyResult> => {
    const lambda = new AWS.Lambda();

    if (process.env.AWS_SAM_LOCAL) {
        lambda.config.endpoint = 'http://127.0.0.1:3000';
    }

    try {
        await lambda
            .invoke({
                FunctionName: 'HelloWorldFunctionB',
                InvocationType: 'Event',
                Payload: JSON.stringify({
                    a: 123,
                    b: 456,
                }),
            })
            .promise();

        return {
            statusCode: 200,
            body: JSON.stringify({
                message: 'hello world 1',
            }),
        };
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return {
            statusCode: 500,
            body: JSON.stringify({
                message: 'some error happened',
            }),
        };
    }
};
```

**HelloWorldFunctionB (the invoked)**

```js
export const lambdaHandler = async (event: APIGatewayProxyEvent): Promise<APIGatewayProxyResult> => {
    try {
        console.log('PROMPT FROM FUNCTION-B');
        return {
            statusCode: 200,
            body: JSON.stringify({
                message: 'hello from function b',
            }),
        };
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return {
            statusCode: 500,
            body: JSON.stringify({
                message: 'some error happened from function b',
            }),
        };
    }
};
```

**template.yaml**

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  sam-test-async

  Sample SAM Template for sam-test-async

# More info about Globals: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/globals.rst
Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 50
    MemorySize: 512
    Tracing: Active
    Environment:
      Variables:
        FUNCTION_PREFIX: ${self:service.name}-${self:provider.stage}

Resources:
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      CodeUri: hello-world/
      Handler: app.lambdaHandler
      Runtime: nodejs18.x
      Architectures:
        - x86_64
      Policies:
        - AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole
        - Version: "2012-10-17"
          Statement:
            - Effect: "Allow"
              Action:
                - "lambda:InvokeFunction"
              Resource: "*"
      Events:
        HelloWorld:
          Type: Api # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
          Properties:
            Path: /hello
            Method: get
    Metadata: # Manage esbuild properties
      BuildMethod: esbuild
      BuildProperties:
        Minify: true
        Target: "es2020"
        Sourcemap: true
        EntryPoints:
          - app.ts

  HelloWorldFunctionB:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      CodeUri: hello-world/
      Handler: app2.lambdaHandler
      Runtime: nodejs18.x
      Architectures:
        - x86_64
      Events:
        HelloWorld2:
          Type: Api # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
          Properties:
            Path: /hello2
            Method: get
    Metadata: # Manage esbuild properties
      BuildMethod: esbuild
      BuildProperties:
        Minify: true
        Target: "es2020"
        Sourcemap: true
        EntryPoints:
          - app2.ts

Outputs:
  # ServerlessRestApi is an implicit API created out of Events key under Serverless::Function
  # Find out more about other implicit resources you can reference within SAM
  # https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/internals/generated_resources.rst#api
  HelloWorldApi:
    Description: "API Gateway endpoint URL for Prod stage for Hello World function"
    Value: !Sub "https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod/hello/"
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Description: "Hello World Lambda Function ARN"
    Value: !GetAtt HelloWorldFunction.Arn
  HelloWorldFunctionIamRole:
    Description: "Implicit IAM Role created for Hello World function"
    Value: !GetAtt HelloWorldFunctionRole.Arn
```

**HelloWorldFunctionB** is working fine when invoked independently and through the api endpoints.

What is missing for the async invocation to work properly? Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to invoke AWS lambda from another lambda within SAM local?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60181387/how-to-invoke-aws-lambda-from-another-lambda-within-sam-local)